# wp_mail not working because Headers From are specified when sending emails

Tags: php, wordpress, email

My wp_mail does not working, but php's normal `mail()` function is working.

This is my formatted php server debug while using wp_mail:

```
[18-Mar-2016 08:40:06 UTC] mail() on [/path/to/public_html/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php:677]:
    To: ***reciever***@gmail.com
    Headers:
        Date: Fri, 18 Mar 2016 08:40:06 +0000
        From: ***website name*** <wordpress@***domain**.ml>
        Message-ID: <02fc36f7060aed6cdc817ce8aad5092a@www.***domain***.ml>
        X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.14 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
        MIME-Version: 1.0
        Content-Type: text/plain;
        charset=UTF-8
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

This is my formatted php server debug on php's `mail()` function:

```
[18-Mar-2016 08:51:10 UTC] mail() on [/path/to/public_html/test/index.php:9]:
    To:***reciever***@gmail.com
    Headers:
```

Seems like email providers like gmail or yahoo blocks my mail because I have `From` stated using wp_mail. I think the problem would be server identity cause the email providers thought I'm trying to spoof my email.

Note: Yes I have wordpress@***domain***.ml as a valid email.

Note: `.ml` is a free domain

Note: Yes I also have SPF record: `v=spf1 mx -all`

Note: I use a proxy on my website (etc: Incapsula, Cloudflare)

Another question: How to get my emails from being marked as spam or how to prevent from being blocked by email providers?